# Distribute 3 chlidren in a parent

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I have a div with three divs in it like this:

```
#parent
   #child-1
   #child-2
   #child-3
```

And I want it to look like this:

[image: The desired layout]

Child 2 should use up the available space vertically, because child-3 is display:none as default, and only on some event it would show up, so it should push child-2 up. child-3 should be as high as it needs to be as well.

I like to use flexbox, but I think I cannot use it here.
It would be really easy to put them in another div, and just do a flex on that box and flex-direction:column, but I do not have this opportunity, so they will be in the same div as child-1.

So what is the easiest way to accomplish this with pure CSS without touching the HTML structure?

Comment: Can you set the parent to a specific/fixed height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one working example:

```css
         #parent {
            height: 50em;
         }
         div[id^=child] {
            border: 2px solid black;
            box-sizing: border-box;
         }
         #child1 {
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 32em;
            background: red;
            width: 30%;
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
         }
         #child2 {
            height: 60%;
            background: green;
            width: calc(70% - .4em);
            margin-left: calc(30% + .4em);
            margin-bottom: .4em;
         }
         #child3 {
            height: calc(40% - .4em);
            min-height: 10em;
            background: yellow;
            width: calc(70% - .4em);
            margin-left: calc(30% + .4em);
         }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>The HTML5</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="parent">
         <div id="child1">
         </div>
         <div id="child2">
         </div>
         <div id="child3">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: almost, but the height of the green one is not using up the space it can use. I mean that child-2 and child-3 together would be the same high as child-1

Comment: That is only achievable if you know the height of the parent-div. If you do not, there is no way you can do that with just CSS - then you need javascript to calculate.

Comment: Updated the code to something with a known height on `#parent`. Then it works as you want.

Comment: The parent height is given! :) And I actually ended up with the same code as you write, while I was trying. ;) But thanks for your help!